# Use Redis to generate unique ID from a limited range

Tags: algorithm, redis, sparse-matrix

I have database items that, in addition to their primary key, need an index unique to the group in which the items belong. Let's call the property `nbr`, and the property that groups items together and defines the scope of unique `nbr`:s we'll call `group`. This `nbr` must be in the [1-N] range, and *may* be set when items are imported from an external source. Since all items must have a `nbr`, the task then becomes how to track which values are used, to enable picking a free `nbr` for new items that are added manually.

I'm using DynamoDB and Redis. I cannot have a DynamoDB index on `nbr`. The idea I have so far is to use Redis to track which numbers have been used for a particular group, so that for a Redis key such as `<MYGROUP>-item-nbrs` I could store all the used `nbr`:s and implement logic to find the next free `nbr`. Holes in the range of used `nbr` is acceptable, but holes should be filled before considering the numbers exhausted.

Essentially I want to find unused indices of a sparse array of max size N.

What would be a good structure for storing this information in Redis to quickly find a free `nbr`? My ideas so far include:

- A single comma-separated string of all used nbr's in sorted order? To find a free nbr, a `GET` command is issued and the string is parsed until a hole is found or the end of the list, the picked number is inserted into the string and then the entire string is replaced. When N is large, this seems very inefficient.
- A hash where each used `nbr` is stored as its own field, and using e.g. `HSCAN` to iterate through the fields of the hash to find a free `nbr`. When N is large, the HSCAN must scan a lot of fields.
- Partitioning my `nbr`:s into fields called say p1-20, p21-40, p41-60, ..., each containing a sorted set of the used `nbr`:s within that partition only, and when a partition is exhausted (no more free `nbr`:s), remove it completely to speed up further iteration. Use HSCAN to iterate, and HSET to start a new partition.
- Storing all free `nbr` instead of all used, and using sorted sets and ZPOPMIN or regular lists and LPOP, possibly partitioned into sub-sets. Pre-populating Redis with all free `nbr` 1-N seems ugly though.

Let's say N is in the magnitude of 65536.

Are any of the solutions above better/worse, for performance or other reasons? Is there a better/smarter way, maybe utilizing some clever aspect of Redis that I'm unaware of?

Edit:

Kevin's answer resulted in the following solution (pseudo code):

```
function getFreeNbr() {
  while (true) {
    send "WATCH numbers"
    nbr = send "BITPOS numbers 0"

    if nbr < N
      send "MULTI"
      send "SETBIT numbers $nbr 1"
      if send "EXEC" != NULL
        return nbr
      end if
    else 
      send "UNWATCH numbers"
      return -1
    end if
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [Bitmaps](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#bitmaps) to record, for every possible `nbr`, whether or not that value is used?

To record that a value is taken use [`SETBIT`](https://redis.io/commands/setbit):

```
SETBIT key [nbr] 1
```

To find a free `nbr` use [`BITPOS`](https://redis.io/commands/bitpos):

```
BITPOS key 0
```

To avoid race conditions you'll want to make sure your get-and-set is atomic. [The OP addresses this in a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568723/redis-bitset-and-watch/54574209).]

This will require very little memory (8K bytes for 65536 possible values). `BITPOS` is O(n), but that's unlikely to be a real problem.

Comment: This looks really promising, great idea! Thanks a lot, I will definitely look into it.

Comment: I updated the question with the result of your suggestion, as pseudo-code including handling the atomicity. Thanks again.

Comment: Late to the party, but I would use INCR. Atomic, pre-settable, fast, good