# Redis BITSET and WATCH

Tags: concurrency, redis, watch, bitset

I'm using Redis to create an algorithm for claiming unused integers from a range. My solution is based on the answer I got for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651878/use-redis-to-generate-unique-id-from-a-limited-range/53654537#53654537) SO question.

This solution uses `BITPOS` and `BITSET`, and to avoid race conditions, I also use `WATCH`/`MULTI`/`EXEC`. In order to test the concurrency aspects I created a bash script that concurrently attempts to find a free number 10 times in parallel, to investigate the possible outcomes of the `EXEC` command.

What I found was that `EXEC` never returned null, even when the watched key was modified by another client. I added delays such that there was plenty of time to provoke a concurrent modification that should trigger the watch mechanism so that `EXEC` fails, but it didn't.

So basically I had this piece of code:

```
while (true) {
  WATCH mykey
  number = BITPOS mykey, 0
  if (number > maxNumber) THROW ERROR

  (deliberate delay)

  MULTI
  SETBIT mykey, number, 1
  if EXEC != null return number
}
```

and also a loop that calls `SETBIT mykey, N, 1` for `N = 1..10`, in 10 different processes.

What I found was that `EXEC` never returned null, even when the key was definitely modified by another process during the watched period of time.

Questions:

1. Is `WATCH` simply not supported for BIT based Redis commands?
2. If it is supported, why wasn't it triggered under these circumstances? Am I testing/provoking it incorrectly? As I understand it, `WATCH` should make `EXEC` fail if the key has been modified *by another client/connection* during the watched period of time, and calling this from 10 different Linux processes, each creating its own connection, seems to fit that requirement?
3. In this particular case, does `WATCH` and `MULTI` actually offer anything? `BITSET` returns the previous value of that bit, so shouldn't atomicity be guaranteed simply by the following pseudo-code algorithm:

```
    while (true) {
      number = BITPOS mykey, 0
      if (number > maxNumber) THROW ERROR

      wasUsed = SETBIT mykey, number, 1

      if (!wasUsed) {
        return number
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no documentation suggesting that `WATCH` doesn't support the bit setting commands.
2. Your code looks right to me, so it's hard to say why it isn't working. To investigate it further you'd have to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than pseudocode. However...
3. You're right, you don't need a transaction here, this algorithm should guarantee atomicity.